# Why does A VB.NET DLL Addin for Inventor compiled on an Intel machine work on the Intel machine but not on AMD?

Tags: vb.net, intel, autodesk, amd-processor

Im developing continually an inventor Addin in VB.Net in visual studio 2019 ,
i have multiple machine different builds , but once in a while some machine just don't want to load the Addin f.e. the current version i have now works on all machines except one AMD machine .

When i compile the same project with the same settings no changes at all on the AMD machine with ANY CPU build option it runs without problem . When i do it on my primary developing machine it does not work on this other computer.

I checked dependencies with dependency walker , i do not get any error messages .

When i make breakpoints in DEBUG mode and debug dll compilation in the first methods called in the "StandardAddInServer.vb" file it does not reach it on the AMD machine when it is compiled on the Intel machine. But in reverse it runs smoothly .

I have no idea what this could be and I'm only speculating that is has to do with AMD/Intel difference of the machines . Any help would be appreciated to come to a solution.

Inventor 2018.3.7 Professional  Build 287 is on the Intel i7-4771 machine Visual Studio Community 2019 16.3.9 , .NET 4.8.03761

Inventor 2018 Professional build 112 is on the AMD Ryzen 7 3700X machine Visual Studio Community 2019 16.7.2 .NET 4.8.03752

Any more information which could be helpful will be provided gladly .

Answer (score 0):

Well.... i tought lets make the maschines identical in regards to software .. i started installing inventor updates one by one at Version 2018.3.1 the Addin magically was working .... so i hope i help somebody if the , addin automatically unloads without any error , its probably autodesk inventors fault ...

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a former framework version like 4.6.2. That should fix the problem. It could be that the newer service packs of Inventor can deal with addins created with newer .net versions. When 2018 Inventor was released, .net 4.8 was not available.

Was Albert wrote is true as well. If the architecture of your dll doesn't meet that of your host process, it can't be loaded. A 64bit process can use 64bit dlls only whereas a 32bit one can deal with 32bit dll only. A .Net project won't be compiled by Studio into fully functional machine code (nowadays you can do this as well), but intermediate code only, which will be compiled finally by the .net framework on the target machine. If anyCPU is selected, you don't have to provide different versions for different hardware because of this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ANY CPU ,or are you forcing the project to a given bit size?

If you don't set this, and leave it at ANY CPU? Well, if you launch the application from Visual Studio (such as installing on that target machine), then the application will run as x32 bits.
HOWEVER if you launch the program from the windows command line (command prompt).
Well, if you use the x64 bit command prompt, you get a x64 bit running - in-process program. If any of your external .dll's or libraryes are x32 (or not compiled with ANY cpu), or you using any un-manage code libraies (say like ghostscript or some such)? Then your program will run (or try to) as x64 bits.

However, if you launch a x32 bit windows command prompt (there are two of them - one is x32, and one is x64). So, if you launch the .net exe (your program) from a windows x32 bit prompt, then your program will run in-process as x32 bits.

So, be careful here. Using ANY CPU from Visual Studio will ALWAYS get you a x32 bit program - including debugging. But RUNNING the program (launching outside of VS) will not always be x32 bits.

And the above behaviours seems to explain your issues/problems on the AMD machine. It was NOT that you installed VS on that machine, but that using VS to launch your program in fact FORCED it to run as x32 bits.

Bottom line:
do NOT use ANY CPU unless that is exactly what you need, and that you are VERY sure any external libraries are also compiled as ANY CPU, or in fact that any external libraries doe NOT USE any un-managed code.

All in all? I would config your project to force run as x86 ALWAYS, and thus you not get some surprises of code not working.

I doubt very much that the AMD CPU is the issue, and installing VS only worked because of forcing your project to run as x32 as opposed to x64 bits. It has zero to do with AMD here.